# Using multiple speech to text APIs to improve accuracy

Tags: artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, google-speech-api

Has anyone ever tried to transcribe audio using two or more speech to text APIs? You could match up the words using time stamps, and pick the word with the highest confidence. If anyone has done this, did it significantly improve the accuracy of the transcription? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 0):

This approach could be problematic for a number of different reasons.  Not all vendors return confidence scores on a word-by-word basis, and even if they did, a confidence of 60% from one vendor does not mean the same thing as a confidence score of 60% from a different vendor's API.  The confidence scores are only valid within the context of the API that is issuing them.

Most speech-to-text vendors have pretty good models at this point.  Some (like IBM Watson) actually allow you to customize the model by adding vocabulary words.  If you look at the industry benchmarks against the SWITCHBOARD corpus, you'll notice that the vendors keep improving and leapfrogging each other.  On 09/13/2016 Microsoft announced it had the lowest error rate (https://blogs.microsoft.com/next/2016/09/13/microsoft-researchers-achieve-speech-recognition-milestone/).  On 01/11/2017 Google claimed to have beaten this, and then IBM claimed superiority on 03/07/2017 (https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2017/03/reaching-new-records-in-speech-recognition/).  The differences have all been a percent or fraction of a percent improvement.  I would expect that this leapfrogging of improvements will continue for the short term.

So to sum it up - By using two different API's you effectively double the cost of your speech to text implementation - which is going to be hard to justify, based on the minimal improvement in accuracy that you would achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard practice for many speech competitions when you do not care about speed of decoding but you need a good accuracy. System combination usually gives you a significant improvements, about 10% more, so it is often beneficial

You do not need timestamps to combine hypothesis properly, you can just compare the outputs statistically. For reference on the subject read

[A PAIRED TEST FOR RECOGNIZER SELECTION WITH UNTRANSCRIBED DATA
Bhiksha Raj, Rita Singh and James Baker](http://mlsp.cs.cmu.edu/people/rsingh/docs/pairedtest.pdf)

[iCNC and iROVER:The Limits of Improving System Combination with Classiﬁcation?
Bjorn Hoffmeister, Ralf Schluter, and Hermann Ney](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221478408_iCNC_and_iROVER_the_limits_of_improving_system_combination_with_classification)

See the implementation of ROVER in [SCTK](https://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools).

Comment: ROVER seems pretty interesting, but also very old. Is there something like it that's more advanced and up to date?